# How to initialize defaultdict with keys?

Tags: python, defaultdict, python-collections

I have a dictionary of lists, and it should be initialized with default keys. I guess, the code below is not good (I mean, it works, but I don't feel that it is written in the pythonic way):

```
d = {'a' : [], 'b' : [], 'c' : []}
```

So I want to use something more pythonic like `defaultict`:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
```

However, every tutorial that I've seen dynamically sets the new keys. But in my case all the keys should be defined from the start. I'm parsing other data structures, and I add values to my dictionary only if specific key in the structure also contains in my dictionary.

How can I set the default keys?

Comment: Do you want additional keys created automatically later or do you have the full set from the beginning?

Comment: If you're using a defaultdict, why do you need to set the keys? What's the behaviour you want, what's the use case for this data structure?

Comment: @tdelaney I want the full set from the beginning.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm parsing other data structures, and I add values to my dictionary only if specific key in the structure also contains in my dictionary.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to provide context and illustrate why your current solution is falling short.

Comment: `I mean, it works, but I don't feel that it is written in the pythonic way` - I don't see any issues with how "pythonic" your existing code is in this case. And wouldn't recommend chasing down every possible instance of 'unpythonic' code in general

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From the comments, I'm assuming you want a dictionary that fits the following conditions:

1. Is initialized with set of keys with an empty list value for each
2. Has defaultdict behavior that can initialize an empty list for non-existing keys

@Aaron_lab has the right method, but there's a slightly cleaner way:

```
d = defaultdict(list,{ k:[] for k in ('a','b','c') })
```

Answer (score 17):

That's already reasonable but you can shorten that up a bit with a dict comprehension that uses a standard list of keys.

```
>>> standard_keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> d1 = {key:[] for key in standard_keys}
>>> d2 = {key:[] for key in standard_keys}
>>> ...
```

Answer (score 11):

If you're going to pre-initialize to empty lists, there is no need for a *defaultdict*.  Simple dict-comprehension gets the job done clearly and cleanly:

```
>>> {k : [] for k in ['a', 'b', 'c']}
{'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': []}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you have a close set of keys (['a', 'b', 'c'] in your example)
you know you'll use, you can definitely use the answers above.

BUT...

`dd = defaultdict(list)` gives you much more then: `d = {'a':[], 'b':[], 'c':[]}`.
You can `append` to "not existing" keys in `defaultdict`:

```
>>dd['d'].append(5)
>>dd
>>defaultdict(list, {'d': 5})
```

where if you do:

```
>>d['d'].append(5)  # you'll face KeyError
>>KeyError: 'd'
```

Recommend to do something like:

```
>>d = {'a' : [], 'b' : [], 'c' : []}
>>default_d = defaultdict(list, **d)
```

now you have a dict holding your 3 keys: ['a', 'b', 'c'] and empty lists as values, **and** you can also append to other keys without explicitly writing: `d['new_key'] = []` before appending

Answer (score 1):

You can have a function defined which will return you a `dict` with preset keys.

```
def get_preset_dict(keys=['a','b','c'],values=None):
    d = {}
    if not values:
        values = [[]]*len(keys)
    if len(keys)!=len(values):
        raise Exception('unequal lenghts')
    for index,key in enumerate(keys):
        d[key] = values[index]

    return d
```

> In [8]: get_preset_dict()
>
> Out[8]: `{'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': []}`
>
> In [18]: get_preset_dict(keys=['a','e','i','o','u'])
>
> Out[18]: `{'a': [], 'e': [], 'i': [], 'o': [], 'u': []}`
>
> In [19]:
>   `get_preset_dict(keys=['a','e','i','o','u'],values=[[1],[2,2,2],[3],[4,2],[5]])`
>
> Out[19]: `{'a': [1], 'e': [2, 2, 2], 'i': [3], 'o': [4, 2], 'u': [5]}`

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
list(map((data := defaultdict(list)).__getitem__, 'abcde'))
data
```

> Out[3]: defaultdict(list, {'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': [], 'd': [], 'e':
> []})